# Running multiple simulation from Simulation Page and capture & show final result in Simulation Page

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I build an experiment with Parameters Variation and need to upload on AnyLogic cloud. But unfortunately there is **no feature of uploading the Parameter Variation experiment in cloud** ( If somebody know the trick how to upload PV experiment in Cloud, let me know).

So now I am **converting Parameter Variation Experiment in General Simulation Model**. In that I am developing a dashboard in **Simulation Page**, from there it will call Main Simulation Model multiple times and store output for each Simulation. Finally at the end it will reconcile all output and will show final result in **Simulation page**.

Here I have following issues

1. Where to write for loop to run multiple Simulation Model. Is it in Simulation page configuration or inside a button in Simulation page and what would be its syntax
2. Currently when we run Main Model, Main page pop up, Which don't need to show to user. It should run all Simulation model at once according to for loop, reconcile output and show in Simulation Page

I also want to mention few more requirements
a. Dont want to show Main Model to user because he will not be interested.
b. All Simulation should run at once ( one by one) at a button click, till that user can wait.
c. For each Simulation I need to pass some input, like one string and one double.
d. As output from each simulation, I need Dataset, double and string variable.

Answer (score 2):

> If somebody know the trick how to upload PV experiment in Cloud, let me know).

There is none. You need to recreate it manually in the cloud as a "Variation" experiment. In the experiment properties there, you can decide which parameters to vary how (using the "Varied in range" option as below):
[image]

Check the [help](https://anylogic.help/cloud/experiment-dashboard.html#settings) for more info on that.

This approach is 100% better than what you try so please follow that route :)